# Sharepoint 2010 Farm plan

Tags: server-farm, capacity-planning, farm-setup

I have a task where I have to propose a farm layout for new project. There will be about 70000 users, and no more than 100 site collections. I estimated requests per second value on 4,66. There will also be search service, profile synchronization service (probably with mysites, but not for all users).

I think about middle-farm deployment scenario, with 3 tiers, with 2 NLB WFE servers, one application server keeping all service applications and database failover cluster.

I was thinking of 4 core @ 2.27 GHz, 8 GB ram for WFE's and application server and 2x4 core @ 2.27, 16GB ram for DB severs. Do you think it might have descent performance on such setup?

Comment: Is it mostly publication or some collaborative sites too? What kind of content will you typically serve (Publishing Pages, Office documents, PDFs, etc.)? What will be the hardware for the filesystems?

Comment: Site collections will be publishing sites and users will have access to discussions, announcements and we will show some static content from external systems. Some of them will be allowed to upload documents (mostly word).

Comment: My initial thought is that 2 * 8GB WFE servers will not be sufficient. I've worked with -much- smaller deployments that had 2 * 16GB RAM for the Web tier. This is of course "finger in the air" but thought it worth sharing.

Comment: Agreed, you would need more than 2 * 8GB WFE servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at HP's Sizer tool for [SP2013](https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA6-2842ENW.pdf) or [SP2016](https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA6-5206ENW.pdf) for SharePoint. It has long been a staple in any farm sizing exercise (their SP2007 and SP2010 no longer seem to be available. Everything will be in terms of HP-branded hardware but you can easily convert to other brands.

They also have a bunch of whitepapers and guides [here](http://h71019.www7.hp.com/activeAnswers/cache/70677-0-0-0-121.html)

70k users is a fairly big farm, I don't know about choosing the middle-farm scenario. My current client at 800 users has a larger setup than you describe (2 WFE, 2 App, 2 SQL, all with 32Gb RAM), but the farm will host their publication intranet, collaborative sites and a bunch of application sites (with Excel Services etc.)

It all depends on the actual load. 4.66 RPS serving cached Publishing Pages is different than serving real-time BI dashboards.

Edit: Found their exact config, edited above.

Comment: Most site collection will be publishing sites, so most of the content will be cached. Only designated groups of user will be able to upload documents and files. Mostly they will use some web parts which are entry point for external systems and make use of blogs, discussions etc.

Comment: @louis, This link (http://h71019.www7.hp.com/activeanswers/Secure/548230-0-0-0-121.html) is not available now, Could you please share another , answer which explains about capacity Planning of SP 2010 farm

Comment: @VirendraKumar Edited the links, but unfortunately it looks like the 2007 / 2010 versions no longer exist. But please don't tell me you are setting up a new farm on those versions today.. :P

Comment: @Louis, Thanks for the updates :) We are setting up 2013 farms.I was looking for  2010 farm values just for comparison in terms of Hardware and software - 2013 v/s 2010.